# annotate in matplotlib places the number 1 off center when saved as a pdf

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib

I am finding that the annotate function in matplotlib places the number 1 off center when the figure is saved as a pdf.  All other numbers appear to be fine.  For example,

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot([0,1], [0,1])

txts = ['1', '2', '3']
y_coords = [0.9, 0.8, 0.7]
for txt, y_coord in zip(txts, y_coords):
    ax.annotate(txt, xy = (0.25, y_coord), \
        size=36, va='center', ha='center', fontname = 'Helvetica', \
        bbox=dict(boxstyle='square', fc = 'w'))

plt.savefig('Test.pdf', bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0)
plt.savefig('Test.jpg', bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0)
```

produces a pdf file that looks like this

[image: pdf]

and a jpg file that looks like this

[image: jpg]

In the pdf, the 1 is not in the center of the rectangle, but the 2 and 3 are in the centers of their respective rectangles.  In the jpg, all three numbers are in the center of their respective rectangles.  If I was creating rasterized images I would be happy with the jpg, but I really want a pdf output.

Is this a bug?  Am I doing something wrong?

I am using Matplotlib 1.2.1 on Python 2.7.3 under Mac OS X 10.8.5

Comment: Seems worthy of a bug-report to me. Can you maybe print `' 1 '` as a workaround?

Comment: as a side note, png is much better than jpg for saving raster images (less artifacts)

Comment: Yeah, if I use `'1 '` (one space after the 1) it moves to the left, but not enough, and if I do `'1  '` (two spaces after the 1) it moves too far.  Perhaps I'll just fix the issue in Adobe Illustrator while I wait for a bug fix...

Comment: @Stretch What version of matplotlib are you using?  And the bug will only get fixed if you report it first;)

Comment: @tcaswell I just updated the posting with the version info.  When/if I report the bug, I will leave a comment here.

Comment: Posted this as issue #2519 on Github.